# How to show extraction progress of 7zip inside cmd?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, progress-bar, command-prompt, 7zip

`7z.exe` do not show any extraction progress in cmd.`"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zG.exe" -y x -pPASSWORD "D:\Myfile.rar"` Extracts the file with a GUI progress-bar. But I don't want a GUI progress bar. I want to show the progress in terms of percentage inside cmd. i.e, I want to use `7z.exe` instead of `7zG.exe` with percentage progress shown.

Answer (score 13):

You can use  **-bsp1** switch to view the progress

```
'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe'  a  -bsp1
```